# How to sync a section in a MutableArray with UITextView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitextview

I have one MutableArray (NSMutableArray *NoteBook;) in which I would like to store Notepages (I set up an object called NotePage.m which simply contains one NSString *noteText and a method to setNoteText). I also have an integer to keep track of my pages (NSUInteger currentPageCounter;).

I start my little program by setting up a new instance of NotePage:

```
NotePage *newPage = [[NotePage alloc] init];
[newPage setNoteText:@"Sample Text for a certain page..."];
```

I then copy this *newPage 3 times into my NoteBook Mutable Array:

```
[self.NoteBook insertObject:newPage atIndex:(self.currentPageCounter)];
```

This will give me 3 pages, at the indices 0,1,2. So far so good. Everything works splendid. But now comes the enemy, UITextView. First of all, I would like to display the contents of a page within my NoteBook in an UITextView. So I did this to sync one section in the MutableArray (e.g. page at index 0) with the UITextView which works fine:

```
NotePage *thisPage = [self.NoteBook objectAtIndex:self.currentPageCounter]; 
TextViewNote.text = thisPage.noteText;
```

The problem is, however, if I want to edit my UITextView and sync the updated text with the MutableArray. This is where the crashing happens... I have coded this in a separate method which can be clicked once the user is done editing the UITextView:

```
    -(IBAction) savePage
{
    NSString *tempString;
    tempString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",TextViewNote.text];

    NotePage *newPage = [[NotePage alloc] init];
    [newPage setNoteText:tempString];

    [self.NoteBook insertObject:newPage atIndex:(self.currentPageCounter)]; // e.g. at index 0 for page 1
    [self.NoteBook removeObjectAtIndex:(currentPageCounter+1)]; // i.e. this is to remove the old page 1 which used to be at index 0 but now is at index 1

    [self syncTextView];
    [self syncCounter];

}
```

I guess there is a less cumbersome way (I'm still a beginner...) to simply replace an object at a certain index at a Mutable Array. As it stands now, it will simply crash once I try to move onwards to the next index position which is apparently not found anymore.

Thanks for any ideas!

Comment: When asking for help with a crash, be sure to always include the error message from the console. Makes it much easier to spot errors if we know what sort of error to look for.

Comment: @Caleb: Sorry, I thought this was more of a conceptual flaw. Here is the error message: 2011-03-21 19:50:58.879 NotePage[13027:207] -[UITouchData length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4b4c0a0
2011-03-21 19:50:58.882 NotePage[13027:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UITouchData length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4b4c0a0' ................ terminate called after throwing an instance of 'NSException'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NSMutableArray` has a method `replaceObjectAtIndex:withObject:` that should do what you are trying to do.

You've got a memory management issue, however, unless you are calling `release` on the `newPage` after you add it to the array. Unless you are planning on making the `NotePage` class more complex, it might make sense simply to change the item's text rather than substituting a new object:

```
[[self.noteBook objectAtIndex:currentPageCounter] setNoteText:tempString];
```

(Also, be aware that inserting the `newPage` object into the array four times does *not* copy the object; it simply inserts the same reference four times. If you want four distinct objects, you will need to allocate four objects in a loop:

```
for(i = 0; i < 4; i++){
    NotePage *newPage = [[NotePage alloc] init];
    [newPage setNoteText:@"Dummy text"];
    [self.notebook addObject:newPage];
    [newPage release];
}
```

Comment: Thanks! When would it be advisable to have different copies of the object? My plan was to load the section from the Mutable Array into the UITextView every time the page changes. Or is this bad programming practice? Should I have a separate object for every page? This could be 30 or so objects, if I had 30 pages. Wouldn't this be a waste of memory resources?

Comment: @n.evermind: Right now, you're creating a new `NotePage` object whenever the text of the page changes anyways. If you want to keep some information (the text of the page) around, you've got to put it somewhere, either in memory or on disk. If you have an array that contains a bunch of pointers to the same object, and you try to change one of the attributes of that object, then you will get that same attribute no matter which index of the array you use: `[[self.notebook objectAtIndex:0] setNoteText:@"Hello"];` `[[self.notebook objectAtIndex:1] noteText] // Returns @"Hello"`

Comment: @n.evermind: I may not fully understand what you're asking. If the user is able to create new pages, then I'd agree, don't set up your array with 30 `NotePage` instances "just in case"; instead, create one only when the user asks for it, and initialize your array probably with just one `NotePage`.

Comment: Thanks so much for your thoughts. I think you're right in all that you're saying. I wasn't really clear about what I need, I guess. Ideally, I'd like to have 30 blank pages, but I guess I could initiate them as I go along, or as the user goes along (lazy loading). I'll give it a try and let you know if it worked

Answer (score 2):

> I guess there is a less cumbersome way
>   (I'm still a beginner...) to simply
>   replace an object at a certain index
>   at a Mutable Array.

Indeed. Look at -[NSMutableArray replaceObjectAtIndex:withObject:].

Considering the error you posted, it sounds like you've got a bad pointer somewhere. The error is complaining that somewhere, a -[UITouchData length] message is being sent to an instance of NotePage. Turn on the 'Stop on Objective-C Exceptions' option in the debugger (under the Run menu). That should help you see where the problem is occurring.